# npm script doesn't not launch karma test correctly

Tags: npm, karma-runner, git-bash, parcel

I'm using parcel to build my project on windows , and installed karma as my test runner. I hope when I changed my source code the parcel would rebuild the project and the karma would execute the test.so I add

```json
  "script": {
     "dev-test": "parcel watch test/* --no-cache & karma start --auto-watch"
  }
```

to my package.json.

The weird thing is when I run "**npm run dev-test**" , **the parcel build the project but karma didn't excute any test**, terminal shows "√  Built in 5.95s.", that's all I got.

I have to type the whole command "**parcel watch test/* --no-cache & npx karma start --auto-watch**" in my command line line(karma isn't installed globally so I have to add npx), it seems to be a workaround, but still have a bug("&" means parcel and karma runs simultaneously so karma would run the test several times when parcel is building project)

I don't want to type the whole command , I hope I can use npm script.

here's my package.json  if it helps

```json
{
  "name": "custom-vue-component",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "parcel build test/* --no-cache --no-minify && karma start --single-run",
    "dev-test": "parcel watch test/* --no-cache &  karma start --auto-watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.1.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-spies": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^5.0.9",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chai-spies": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^2.0.2",
    "mocha": "^7.2.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "sass": "^1.26.7",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "alias": {
    "vue": "./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  }
}
```

and karma.conf.js

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["mocha", "sinon-chai"],
    client: {
      chai: {
        includeStack: true,
      },
    },
    files: ["dist/**/*.test.js", "dist/**/*.test.css"],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ["progress"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["ChromeHeadless"],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are Windows user, you maybe meet this problem.
You can solve it by run `parcel watch test/* --no-cache &  karma start` separately:

1. Open a git bush window and run `npx parcel watch test/* --no-cache`
2. Open another git bush window and run `npx karma start`